# Tag null in kotlin android

Tags: android, image, kotlin

i'm trying change images using tag but this returns null and i don't know why. This is my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val iv = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv)
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.morado)


    iv.setOnClickListener{
        val path = R.drawable.verde
        val s = iv.getTag(path.toString().toInt())
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: $s") //here $s is null but the file 'verde' exist
        //iv.setImageResource(a)
    }
}
```

Why $s is null? can anyone explain me that?

Comment: Where do you call `setTag`? The tag is a custom attribute and is not set by default, which is why it is null. What are you trying to do here anyway, change which image is shown?  If so you could just call `iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.verde)`.  Also, path is already an int so calling `toString().toInt()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to do that was:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val iv = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv)
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.morado)

    iv.setOnClickListener{
        iv.tag = R.drawable.verde
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: ${iv.tag.toString().toInt()}")
        iv.setImageResource(iv.tag.toString().toInt())
    }
}
```